# AWS S3 SDK How to specify aws account id when accessing bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I am writing an app that will upload files to an S3 bucket that belonging to another account.
It works fine but I am worried about security.

Where will the file end up and is it possible for me to specify the id of **AccountA**?
Neither the AWS S3 nor the go documentation seems to give any hints if it is possible.

**AccountA (the good guy)**
Creates a bucket named "theBucket" and shares it with AccountC (my account)

**AccountB (The interceptor)**
Creates a bucket named "theBucket" and shares it with AccountC (my account)

**AccountC (my account)**
Run the following simplified golang code

```
    uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(sess)

    _, err = uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("theBucket"),
        Key:    aws.String("my.file"),
        Body:   file,
    })
```

Comment: S3 bucket names are **globally unique**. The only way for `AccountB` to create `theBucket` is if `AccountA` first deletes `theBucket`.

Comment: Thank you that answers my question.